# Using a shell subprocess to determine whether a second script is still running

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess, stdout

I have two semi-depended python scripts. ScriptA should run, even if ScriptB is not. ScriptB instead should only continue if ScriptA is running.

My idea was something like

```
 proc = subprocess.Popen(["ps aux | grep scriptA.py | wc -l"],shell=True,STDOUT=X)
```

and somehow check if the result is `2` (as it would be `1`, due to the grep).

I receive `2`, when testing in python console but I struggle saving the stdout. Tried to use `stdout=variable` but that failed. When i was using a `string` the subprocess failed (with `c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()`), when using an `int` it was always 0.

Comment: use a pid file for all your scripts: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12815/what-are-pid-and-lock-files-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', 'scriptA.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

process.wait()

if not process.returncode:
    print "Process running"
else:
    print "Process not running"
```

Here, I use pgrep to search for the process, and check its return code instead of its output.

If you want to use the stdout, you can use `process.stdout`.
It's a file like object.

Comment: I like it, but how about `stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`?

Comment: @tdelaney Sure, if you don't care about the output, you can redirect it to /dev/null. This doesn't change the return code and the above code will still work. Btw, `os.devnull` can be used to get the cross plataform file path.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion! I'll try that and report back with results!

Comment: @Fedalto: your code can deadlock on `process.wait()` if `pgrep` generates output that overflow its stdout OS pipe buffer (though it is unlikely). tdelaney's `DEVNULL` approach avoids it and it should be used in general.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Popen.poll()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll)? If it returns `None`, the process hasn't terminated yet. If it returns a number, it's the exit code of the process.

Comment: From the python documentation "Check if child process has terminated". Yet ScriptA is no child process of ScriptB, would this work anyways?

Comment: ohboy.. i think i misunderstood you, you meant to use `Popen.poll()` on the `ps aux | grep ScriptA.py` right?